# Hat does not display fully on a user's activity page

Tags: bug, design, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

<sub>I'm aware Winter Bash is ending soon, but perhaps this could be fixed for next year's WB.</sub>

As seen in the image below, my hat does not display fully.

> [image]

It appears that this can be fixed by removing `overflow: hidden` from `[class * ="gravatar-wrapper-"]` in `primary.css`.

```
[class * ="gravatar-wrapper-"] {
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden
}
```

Comment: It is the same on all the profile's (upper right) avatar area, but [different elsewhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aA1af.jpg), such as the [user list searcher](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hat in profile image overflow: hidden](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358804/hat-in-profile-image-overflow-hidden)